# For my specific use which hd will serve me better 64mb cache 5400 rpm or 32mb 7200 rpm?

Tags: windows-7

I will be downloading roughly 650 GB of music files to a 1 TB external HD. When I play back the music which HD will be best for my needs a HD with 64mb cache 5400 rpm or 32mb 7200 rpm?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously? Unless you're going to be playing back 1000 files all at the same time, it really doesn't matter what you get. Playing mp3 files is *not* an IO-intensive task.

Answer (score 1):

Either HD could handle playing your music back without a problem. Cache is useful... sometimes. But faster spindles are always better to have, performance wise. Go for the 7200.

Comment: How about life-time? Wouldn't faster drives kill it faster?